# PyOpenGL error when rendering a textured Sun with a gluSphere

Tags: python, opengl

I'm writing a program to simulate our Solar system for my Computer Graphics' project. I'm using Python as programming language and Pygame (to control display, mouse and keyboard events), PyOpenGL (for 3D modelling and texture) and PIL (Python Image Library, to load images for OpenGL textures). The main point of the application is to be able to fly arund in the solar system through the keyboard (a sort of free camera game). I used the firstopengl.py approach of the  "Beginning
Game Development with Python and Pygame From Novice to Professional" book, by Will McGugan, to control the camera. My problem is that when I run the program (rendering only the textured sun in the center of the scene) it works perfectly well until you move either too close or too far from the object (rotating has showed no problems so far). The error output is:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe E:/Nestor/RESPALDO/NESTOR/DATA/7mo_Semestre/GxC/Proyecto/star-trip/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Nestor/RESPALDO/NESTOR/DATA/7mo_Semestre/GxC/Proyecto/star-trip/main.py", line 235, in <module>
main()
  File "E:/Nestor/RESPALDO/NESTOR/DATA/7mo_Semestre/GxC/Proyecto/star-trip/main.py", line 225, in main
        planets[0].render()
  File "E:\Nestor\RESPALDO\NESTOR\DATA\7mo_Semestre\GxC\Proyecto\star-trip\spaceobjects.py", line 46, in render
    baseline.loadTexture(self.texture)
  File "E:\Nestor\RESPALDO\NESTOR\DATA\7mo_Semestre\GxC\Proyecto\star-trip\baseline.py", line 158, in loadTexture
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, ix, iy, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyopengl-3.1.0-py2.7.egg\OpenGL\latebind.py", line 41, in __call__
    return self._finalCall( *args, **named )
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyopengl-3.1.0-py2.7.egg\OpenGL\wrapper.py",   line 875, in wrapperCall
    raise err
OpenGL.error.GLError
```

At first glance it seems like I'm doing something wrong when applying the sun's texture so here's the code I used to do it:

```
def loadTexture(texture_path):

    #Load texture file
    data = open(texture_path)
    ix = data.size[0]
    iy = data.size[1]
    data = data.tostring("raw", "RGBX", 0, -1)

    # Create textures
    textures = glGenTextures(3)

    # Select our current texture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, int(textures[0]))   # 2d texture (x and y size)

    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT,1)
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, ix, iy, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data)

    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP)
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP)
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT)
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT)
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)

    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL)

    # Create Linear Filtered Texture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, int(textures[1]))

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, ix, iy, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data)

    # Create a MipMapped Texture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, int(textures[2]))

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST)

    gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, ix, iy, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data)

    return textures
```

I'm also getting "Insufficient memory" errors that I don't quite understand so any optimization advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you calling loadTexture repeatedly? It kind of sounds like it, although it's a bit hard to tell from your code, but the fact that the exception occurs well after you start up (when you are close to the sun, for instance) is a sign that it's being called in the render loop.

If you are calling it every rendering loop, then you will be allocating gazillions of identical texturemaps (and building gazillions of mipmaps), which will chew through graphics memory very quickly. Make sure you are calling loadtextures only once, saving the returned texture ids, and then just calling glBind2D with those ids, rather than calling loadtexture over and over.

Comment: Your guess about the loadTexture function is correct. I call it once per frame in the main loop. I'm not versed on how to handle memory usage in OpenGL (or in Computer Graphics for that matter, I'm learning from scratch :) ) so I guess I made a classic rookie mistake. I'll try your approach and see what happens. Thanks a lot...

PS: If you can recommend a good tutorial on this matter it would come in handy.

Comment: The NeHe tutorials are generally good, and most have been translated into python (for instance, one on texture mapping:http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/context/tutorials/nehe6.html)

Comment: By the way, if you found the answer helpful, please accept it as the answer :)